# Processes show overflowing Virtual Size

Tags: process-explorer

I have two virtual machines where all the processes exhibit the following behaviour:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMaAZ.png

The screenshot is from Process Explorer and for each process the numbers are different, but they overflow.

The rest of the VMs (10 others) don't have this issue. For all intents and purposes, all VMs are identical in spec.

Not sure if relevant but:

- Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition Service Pack 2
- 2.6 GHz Six-Core AMD Opteron
- 1 GB RAM

Has anyone else seen this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging, turns out it's a PE bug.

http://forum.sysinternals.com/process-explorer-v1204-bug_topic23128_post120161.html